# Unable to process string inside mysql_query() function in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am having an array of fields and after using `implode` function and converting them to string, I am trying to use this string as names of columns in `mysql_query()` function as follows:

```
$field_array = array('course','batch','branch');

$fields = implode(", ",$field_array);
$resource = mysql_query("SELECT $fields FROM some_table") or die(mysql_error());
```

but I am getting the following error. What is that I am doing wrong here ?

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM fix_data' at line 1
```

Below is the exact code I am using

```
function fetch_resource_db_nowhere($table_name,$field_array,$return_type,$return_type_name) {



    if($field_array[0]=='ALL') {
        //echo "asda";
        $resource = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$table_name."") or die(mysql_error());
    }
    else {
        $fields = implode(",",$field_array);
        $sql = "SELECT ".$fields." FROM ".$table_name."";
        echo $sql;
        $resource = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    }


    if($return_type == 'resource') {
        return $resource;
    }

    if($return_type == 'resource_array') {
        return mysql_fetch_assoc($resource);
    }

    if($return_type == 'resource_array_value') {
        $resource_array = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource);
        return $resource_array[$return_type_name];
    }


}

$data = fetch_resource_db_nowhere('fix_data',array('course','branch','name'),'resource','');
```

Comment: what does `echo "SELECT $fields FROM some_table";` yield?

Comment: `SELECT course,branch,name FROM fix_dataSELECT FROM fix_data` this is the exact out put I am getting. now something is definitely wrong here.

Answer (score 3):

You were trying to implode an array called field_array, even though your example shows an array called fields_array:

```
$fields_array = array('course','batch','branch');
$fields = implode(", ",$fields_array);
$resource = mysql_query("SELECT $fields FROM some_table") or die(mysql_error());
```

Edit: You changed your code again. Could you please give us the exact code that you're working with?

Comment: @Rijk I just updated the answer. He was imploding an array called field_array when it was actually an array called fields_array.

Comment: Removed my downvote. Even though I think it's not the answer to his problem (read the error).

Comment: Of course it's the answer, syntax near from because the fields is empty.

Comment: If the implode was incorrect, he'd be selecting nothing, which would cause the SQL error in question.

Comment: Error says `near 'FROM fix_data'`. Where does "fix_data" come from?

Comment: @Rijk He renamed the table name for this example.

Comment: @hsinxh And you're still getting the error? It seems as if you're trying to hide certain details from us. Could you provide us with the exact code that you're using?